# How to write a script that interacts with web browser and print content as PDF?

Tags: scripting

I'm looking to write an automated script that

1. Opens up a browser instance with a specific URL
2. Print the page as PDF output to a pre-defined location and document name
3. Simulate a click event on the web page that goes to the next report
4. Repeat 2 and 3 for a fixed number of times.

I'm not sure how to start doing this. Thought of using Javascript, but it won't be able to automate the printing process.

There is no control of the server, therefore I cannot use a query to get the collection of those reports.

The reason for the script is that there are many such reports, and the server can be very slow at times, it would be better to have them locally.

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that log in is required for the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think scripting an off-the-shelf browser is very much the Hard Way to solve your problem. If you can at all predict the URLs for the individual report, use a command-line tool such as wget or curl to download them, and then look at [this community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters) for rendering the downloaded HTML as PDF.

Or do you even need to go to PDF? If all you're interested in is having the reports available locally, why not keep them as HTML and view them in a browser (with a `file:` URL) rather than a PDF viewer?

Comment: Well forgot to mention that log in is required, so wget doesn't quite work.